# Run jbehave tests on multiple browsers in parallel using multi-thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, selenium, jbehave

I have done a lot searching but cannot find a solution.

I am currently using the jebhave, spring project to setup my automated tests. This can be found here:
https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-tutorial/tree/master/etsy-selenium/java-spring

The archetype is "org.jbehave:jbehave-spring-archetype"
http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/archetypes.html

Currently the setup uses spring to inject the FirefoxWebDriverProvider but I need to somehow run these tests in Chrome and IE as well in parallel. I have found that using a PropertyWebDriverProvider allows me to run in different browsers if I set the system properties but I currently have to manually choose this by commenting out lines of code.

The spring xml has the following:

```
<bean id="driverProvider" class="org.jbehave.web.selenium.PropertyWebDriverProvider" >
</bean>

<bean id="webDriverProvider" class="org.jbehave.web.selenium.PerStoryWebDriverSteps">
    <constructor-arg ref="driverProvider"/>
</bean>

<bean id="lifecycleSteps" class="com.three.automation.steps.LifecycleSteps">
    <constructor-arg ref="driverProvider"/>
</bean>
```

Running this defaults to Firefox Driver unless I specify system properties (one at a time for each browser):

```
System.setProperty("browser", "chrome");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe");


//System.setProperty("browser", "ie");
//System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src/main/resources/IEDriverServer.exe");
```

Is there a way setting this up so it automatically injects each driverprovider and runs tests on different threads?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: why not try testng for parallel executions?

Comment: I cannot seem to find much on setting up jbehave and testng. Also integrating this with spring to inject the drivers is not an easy thing for me to get working.